# Unable to build SWIG.exe using MinGw

Tags: python, mingw, swig, pocketsphinx

I am trying to install 'pocketsphinx' module in python which requires swig.exe. After a lot of searching I followed the steps mentioned in the swig site(http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Windows.html#Windows_swig_exe) to build an exe. But I am stuck at the last 2 steps. 
When './autogen.sh' is executed, I get the following error message although the file 'aclocal' is present in the '/mingw/bin' directory.

vinay@DESKTOP-7LB2J5M /usr/src/swig
$ ./autogen.sh
+ test -d Tools/config
+ aclocal -I Tools/config
./autogen.sh: /mingw/bin/aclocal: No such file or directory

I renamed c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\fstab.sample to c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\fstab and also installed automake, libtool, autoconf, aclocal, autoheader dependencies from MinGW installation manager. What am I missing?

I am not familiar with MinGw or unix commands.

Comment: You can download prebuilt swigwin package from sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/swig/files/swigwin/swigwin-3.0.12/swigwin-3.0.12.zip/download it already contains required binary.

Comment: It works. @Nikolay Shmyrev, thanks a lot.